# How to get a password from Wildfly

Tags: java, security, wildfly, elytron

I have a password to some service. I need to save it in WildFly 19 and then get it in a java application.

I found a certain amount of information, but I'm not sure if it's outdated.

1. Do I need vault?
2. How do I write my password to the Wildfly? I found the following commands. Is this enough to save the password?

```
/subsystem=elytron/credential-store=test:add(relative-to=jboss.server.data.dir, location=test.jceks, create=true,credential-reference={clear-text=storepass})

/subsystem=elytron/credential-store=test:add-alias(alias=keystorepw,secret-value=secret)
```

3. How do I get a password in a java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, vaults are [a legacy tool](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#Security_Vault_Migration) and you should use a credential store to secure passwords.
2. Yes, those commands should be sufficient. You can find more information in the [Elytron documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#create-and-use-a-credential-store). The [docs for the current Wildfly 26.1](https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#CredentialStore) may also be helpful.
3. You can find [an example application here](https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/tree/main/credential-store).

Comment: Thanks, the example helped me figure it out. But I still have one question: in line `СlearPassword.createRaw(ClearPassword.ALGORITHM_CLEAR, "ExamplePassword".toCharArray());`, I need to specify the password from the storage, which I also have to get from somewhere, since it may be different for different servers. It turns out that it should be stored in the vault

Comment: If you added the password using the CLI commands in (2), you should be able to retrieve it [by referencing its alias](https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/blob/58a4b3c78883ba5e1802535bbaafac128d160d08/credential-store/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/examples/CredentialStoreExample.java#L80).

The store is saved as a file, so you can add it to other servers by using the same `add` CLI command with an updated filepath. You can also create a store [with the included bash script](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#keystorecredentialstore).

Comment: I'm sorry, I copied the wrong line. I'm talking about the password for the store `Password storePassword = ClearPassword.createRaw(ClearPassword.ALGORITHM_CLEAR, "StorePassword".toCharArray())` To get it by alias, I need to initialize store, and for this I need a password `ProtectionParameter protectionParameter = new CredentialSourceProtectionParameter(IdentityCredentials.NONE.withCredential(new PasswordCredential(storePassword)));
        credentialStore.initialize(configuration, protectionParameter);`

Comment: Ah, then yeah in that case you need either some secure storage, or you can use a masked password instead ([details](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#Passwords), [implementation](https://docs.wildfly.org/19/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#referencing-credentials))